# Widget Logic WordPress Exclude a Parent Category and it's Children?

Tags: wordpress, parent, parent-child, categories

I am trying to only show a single parent category and it's children on a specific category page.

How do I exclude all other parent categories and their children?

I am using the plugin Widget Logic. I have gone through the usage and can't quite figure it out.

I have it setup to show just the widget for that category on that categories page, but it won't exclude the categories that aren't associated with that categories page.

I also tried using a custom bit of code accessed from my " functions.php " but no go.

Help appreciated.

*** Here is the Widget Logic I have in place: ***

```
is_category(6) || (is_single() && in_category(6))
```

*** Here's the visual result thus far: ***

> **RECENT INSPIRATION POSTS** -- Widget
>
> Test for Inspiration July 20th, 2012
>
> Test Inspiration May 24th, 2012
>
> **INSPIRATION CATEGORIES** -- Widget
>
> *Inspiration*
>
> -- inspiration child
>
> *News* (this is a parent category that should not be listed???)
>
> -- news child (this is a child category that should not be listed???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured this one out. I was actually thinking incorrectly. Not a widget logic issue. I found this Plugin instead.

AVH Extended Categories

This plugin lets you group, re-order and display particular categories within a category widget. Pretty sweet.